# Is there any way to create channels in Parse.com via REST API?

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm working in a Ionic App to report potholes in the city. The user can make reports through the App or the Webpage, then other users can comment this issue and receive notifications about this specific topic.

I read the documentation for Parse.com of how to send push notifications for specific channels, for example, each report is a different channel. So if I comment in the report 123214 so automatically I will subscribe to this channel in Parse.com and receive notifications. Already know how to do this.

But Is there any way of create these channels in the same time that I generate the report in the App using javascript and REST API request ?

best regards